# Elastic database transaction with sql azure causing error 8510

Tags: azure-sql-database

We have two V12 databases in ET(elastic transaction) using .NET 4.6.1. I can see before the error occurs that transaction is promoted to elastic in first database from sys.dm_tran_active_transactions views transaction_uow column.

When we call following code to open connection to second database we get error: "The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 8510.
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded"

```
Error happens when calling connection.open()

Using connection = CreateConnection()

End Using

Protected Function CreateConnection(connectionString As String) As IDbConnection
    Try
        Dim connection = DbProviderFactory.CreateConnection()
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString
        connection.Open()
        Return connection
    Catch ex As DbException
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to fix this by setting exact same database options to all databases by comparing sys.databases. For example some of our databases were using snapshot isolation and some not.